# jquery validation plugin, conditional remote call not working as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery, coffeescript, jquery-validate

I am trying to setup a conditional remote call using the standard jquery validation plugin.

The problem is when I pass in the name.val() in the validate method it's always the name that was set in the input text field when the page loads. It's never the name in the text box.

I replaced name.val() with "Test" and then the script works flawlessly. There are no syntax errors or any errors in the console. **I also removed the call to get_exists_rule(name.val()) and replaced it with a simple required: true and it's fine. I have this setup working on other forms with the same naming scheme, just no remote calls.**

I also threw an alert msg in the get_exists_rule and no matter what it only gets executed once when the page loads so there might be some funny business going on.

I've been stuck on this for close to 7 hours straight, I looked at every related SO post and everywhere I could think of and did not find a solution that works.

**Here's the coffeescript:**

```
  name = $("#category_name")

  get_exists_rule = (category_name) ->
    if original_name is category_name
      required: true
      maxlength: 64
    else
      remote: { url: "/dashboard/categories/exists/" + title_to_slug(category_name), type: "POST", async: false }

  category_form.validate
    errorElement:
      "span"
    rules:
      "category[name]":
        get_exists_rule(name.val())
```

**Here's the javascript:**

```
var get_exists_rule, name;

name = $("#category_name");

get_exists_rule = function(category_name) {
  if (original_name === category_name) {
    return {
      required: true,
      maxlength: 64
    };
  } else {
    return {
      remote: {
        url: "/dashboard/categories/exists/" + title_to_slug(category_name),
        type: "POST",
        async: false
      }
    };
  }
};

category_form.validate({
  errorElement: "span",
  rules: {
    "category[name]": get_exists_rule(name.val())
  }
});
```

Comment: What is name.val() at that point?

Comment: When the page loads it's the value of the input field, it never changes from that value.

Comment: So what is name? Is it a jquery obj that refers to the input?

Comment: Yes, I edited the post to include that, it's just a reference to the node by id. I also tried just referencing it straight up without the extra variable in case some crazy weird caching issue occurred, but it also fails.

Comment: Well, if you pass name.val() to the function that returns your rule, it will pass the value at the time the page loads. So original_name will always === category_name

Comment: How would I get around that? The use case is I need to send my server the category name only if the name differs from the original and then report back the validation result on the client side. Also keep in mind if I replace category_name in the function call to "Test" then the remote function does get called (in this case "Test" is a name of a category).

Comment: It makes sense that it would work if you replace category_name with test, if original_name != 'Test'. On the other hand, name.val() is always === to original_name on page load because you haven't had a chance to change it.

Comment: What do you think needs to be done to fix the situation so it works as intended?

Comment: You can try to change the rule whenever category_name changes. So add a change event listener and if category_name != original_name, modify the validation rule.

Comment: Look at this: http://jqueryvalidation.org/rules#.22add.22rules

Comment: I'm not sure how to apply the rules adding/deleting. In this case it's either rule set #1 or rule set #2 depending on a condition, rather than "yes a rule needs to happen" and "no rules is fine". Also struggling to modify the validation rule in the event handler.

Comment: What you should do is add the initial rule as if category_name is = to original_name. Then on change of category_name, do the add rule call to add the remote rule. See the link I added in my previous comment.

Comment: I did look at it, it seems like you can only add an unnamed rule but then you can remove rules by name but I have no idea what the name of my custom rules would be.

Comment: You don't have a custom rule. Your initial rules will be "required" and "maxlength" and then if category_name changes, you will add the rule "remote". Those are all standard rules.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make the initial rule the same as when category_name === original_name.
Then when category_name changes, add the remote rule.

Something like this:

```
$('#category_name').on('change', function() {
  $( "#category_name" ).rules( "add", {
    remote: {
      url: "/dashboard/categories/exists/" + title_to_slug(category_name),
      type: "POST",
      success: function(exists) {
        if(title_to_slug(category_name) === original_name) {
          return true;
        else {
          return exists;
        }
      }
    }
  });
});
```

**EDIT**

Solution using the validator's remote rule by default instead of adding the rule on change.

```
rules: {
  "category[name]": {
    required: true
    maxlength: 64
    remote: {
      url: "/dashboard/categories/valid_category",
      type: "POST",
      data: {
        "category[name]": function() { 
           return title_to_slug(name.val());
        },
        original_name: original_name
      }
    }
  }
}
```

On server side do something like this in your language:
You need to return a json string of "true" or "false".

```
if (post["category[name]"] == original_name)
  return "true"
else 
  return category_exists(post["category[name]"])
```

Comment: This almost works, I changed it to be attached to the form's "submit" event so it's less spammy. The new problem is, let's say I do these steps: 1. change the category to be a name I know exists, it then properly gives me a fail message , 2. change the category to be an ok name , it still fails but then if I go back and change it again and switch fields / come back then it lets me pass. Thoughts on how to fix that behavior? Really appreciate the help btw. The same applies if I put it on the change/blur event of the field too.It also fails if try to submit it with the original name all the time

Comment: Where are you setting original_name? Are you sure that's not changing?

Comment: I set it at the top of the file, and it's a copy of name.val(). Also I applied your on change rule to the form submit event but it still seems to fire when the field changes, I can feel it lagging the input. Any idea why?

Comment: Here's the entire cs file: http://pastie.org/8355512 , and the js version: http://pastie.org/8355517 -- I'm not sure why pastie is adding an extra -> to the first function, ignore that. Also I changed my server to accept a GET instead of POST so I could debug the exists method easier (it does work).

Comment: I'm not sure how to use it to debug this issue, I've only been console logging. It feels like something is broken with the remote calls. It's noticeably lagging my computer, now I got it to somehow submit with a name that should have not passed.

Comment: Why are you adding attach_js twice? See bottom of JS file.

Comment: That is because of turbolinks and rails. Turbolinks requires you to have your JS loaded for the page:load event but you also need to bind it to dom ready so it works on a fresh full load.

Comment: You set your remote rule to `async: false`. You should remove that. The remote rule uses a standard ajax call and it defaults to `async:true` so it doesn't lock up the browser.

Comment: The way you have it now, you are adding the rule on submit without any conditions. This means that you might as well add the remote rule by default because it will always add it on submit.

Comment: Ok changing async to false fixed the lag issue. I also changed the event to occur on both name.blur and name.keyup with name.on "blur keyup" and now it all works EXCEPT I can't submit the form when the original name and the name is the same.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38056/discussion-between-antelopesalad-and-vlad)

Comment: I just want to publicly state that Vlad is a champion among men. We spent 3 hours in chat debugging it and finally got it working perfectly. He went totally out of his way to do that and for that I thank him. I'll be awarding him as much rep as possible through a bounty as soon as it lets me.